# Using the OpenShift API is there a way to get deployments in a project

Tags: openshift-3

I am doing some recon work on projects in our openshift cluster and I am looking for an easy way to get all the Projects in a certain group.

I know there is an openshift API that has access to certain openshift artifacts:

For example I could make an API call to the openshift cluster like this:

```
/oapi/v1/projects/{name}
```

To get a project of a specific name.
Is there a way to then get all the deployments for that project... Something like this:

```
/oapi/v1/projects/{name}/deployments
```

So I could know what deployments are in a certain environment in our openshift cluster.

Any thoughts on this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCP`"Projects"` being a superset or "encapsulation" of k8s`"Namespaces"`, you can list the deployments of a specific`"Project/Namespace"` with this API:

```
GET /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments
```

Of course you need the correct autorizations to be able to list such objects as explained in the following docs

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/deployment-v1/#http-request-2

OCP API Reference: https://docs.okd.io/latest/rest_api/index.html
K8S API Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/

Comment: that sir, seems like just about what I am looking for.